# Doxygen support for only custom classes in stl containers

Tags: c++, stl, doxygen

I just started using doxygen and discovered the very useful configuration:

```
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT = YES
```

What I am wondering is if there is any way to limit the scope of this? (Not the C++ technical meaning of scope, but the scope of doxygen's understanding.) In particular it would be great to have STL containers *only* appear for wrapping custom classes. For example if I had the following:

```
class B;
class A
{
    std::vector<char> vectorOfChar;
    std::vector<B> vectorOfObjects;
};
```

It would be great to have doxygen show the `vector<B>` in the collaboration diagram *without* the `vector<char>` appearing. Is this possible at all with configuration options, or custom header files, or modifying the built-in stl support?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your project, I could think of 2 work-arounds for your case, both are not optimal:

- There are only a few instances where a STL object should be displayed: Here you can remove the `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT` flag and document each symbol you want to see. e.g you document your `std::vector<B>` type.
- A lot of stl types should be shown, only default ones removed: Here you can Exclude symbols, using `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS`. You can exclude `std::vector<char>` for Example, and it won't show up in the dependency graph. This may be a lot of work, but you can use Wildcards for generalization.

Unfortunately both are not very convenient solutions, but maybe it's better than nothing.

Links: http://cs.swan.ac.uk/~csoliver/ok-sat-library/internet_html/doc/doc/Doxygen/1.7.6.1/html/config.html#cfg_exclude_symlinks

Comment: I did try `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` and I couldn't seem to get it to do what I want. But for your other work-around, would I need to forward-declare the vector container and comment that? Or would I use some sort of `\ingroup` (or similar) command on a dangling comment block?